# Connecting to Amazon RDS from local machine through an ec2-instance bridge

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-rds, pgadmin

**Hello all**

I have a dabase seted up in RDS. Right now there is a ec-instance which is my test enviroment which connects to that RDS and working on a particular DB.

Now something with a migration might have messed up the data in that database.
What I am trying to do is connect to that database using pgAdmin 3 to check what's going on.

What I did is used the connect to a new server of pgAdmin
and used the SSH Tunnel tab.

In the properties I used the credentials of the RDS and in the SSH Tunnel(tab)
I used the ssh files I am using to connect to the testing instance I already know has access to the RDS.

Problem is I am getting

> Error: SSH error: Error when starting up SSH session with error code
> -8 [Unable to exchange encryption keys]

Does my logic make sense ?
Meaning to use the SSH tunnel to configure a connection to an ec2 instance and assume that throught this tunnel the pgAdmin is going to be able to connect to the actuall RDS hosted database ?
Any direction on how to proceed further are greatly appriciated !

Comment: Can you shown ssh command that you use for the tunnel? Also if you login to your instnace, can you connect to the rds from there?

Comment: Can you connect to the bridge with putty for instance?

Comment: @Marcin yes I can connect to the rds from the instance. I am not using any command for the tunneling I am just filling the information in the tunneling tab of pgAdmin

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson Can you explain further what you are saying ?

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question.  As I read it (first) I gathered you where connecting from a localmachine thru EC to the RDS and therefore was just wondering where the problem is.  Perhaps you are having this problem connecting directly from the EC to the RDS (and my question therefore irrelevant)?